# Kolmogorov's Event axioms

Tags: probability-theory

*Note: Book I am using is showing Kolomogorov as the founder of these axioms as well as of widely known Probability Axioms, so I would be grateful If someone answered what is the original name of above-mentioned event axioms.*

Given some $\mathcal F$, which is the subset of $P(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is event set, $\mathcal F$ will be $\sigma$-algebra if is fulfills these three axioms:

$$1.\quad\Omega \in \mathcal F $$
 $$2.\quad A \in \mathcal F \Rightarrow \bar{A} \in \mathcal{F}$$
 $$3.\quad \{A_i\}_{i \in \Bbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{F} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \bigcup_{i = 1}^{\infty} {A_i} \in \mathcal{F}$$

**My question:** What is the easiest way derive this additional characteristic of $\sigma$-algebra by using above axioms:
$$\quad \{A_i\}_{i \in \Bbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{F} \quad  \Rightarrow \quad \bigcap_{i = 1}^{\infty} {A_i} \in \mathcal{F}$$
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B\in \mathcal F$ then $\overline B\in \mathcal F$ as well. Then refer to De Morgan's law $$\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=\overline {\overline {\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i}}=\overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\overline{A_i}}\in \mathcal F.$$